# bootstrap 4 disable mx-auto at certain viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, viewport

I have two buttons that when in responsive screens they need to be horizontally centered one below each other and in larger screens they need to be one beside each other also centered.

```
              <!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>Hello, world!</title>
              <!-- Required meta tags -->
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">


               <style>

                 section.masthead2{
                    background-color:orange;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-attachment: scroll;
                    background-position: center center;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
                    height:80vh;
                    position:relative;
                  }
                  .gear {
                    height: 50px;

                  }
                  .botonhome{
                    background-color:#eb6626;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    padding-left:2em;
                    padding-right:2em;
                    font-family:'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-weight:500;
                    border-radius:0.5em;
                    font-size:1.2em;
                    width:200px;
                  }
                  /*.contain{
                    position:absolute;
                    left:50%;
                    right:0;
                    transform:translateX(-50%);
                    bottom:0;
                  }*/
               </style>

            </head>
            <body>
            <section class="container-fluid masthead2 d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <h1 class="textoprincipal text-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col d-sm-flex  justify-content-center ">
                      <a class="btn botonhome   mr-sm-3 mb-3 " routerLink="/backoffice/job" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
                      <a class="btn  botonhome    mb-3 " routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
                    </div>         
                </div>
              </div>
                <!--<div class="contain bg-danger">-->
                <!--<img class="gear contain" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Cog%2C_Web_Fundamentals.svg">-->

                <!--</div>-->
            </section>



            </section>
              <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
              <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
            </body>
          </html>
```

What happens in responsive is that the buttons stay on the left side of the screen instead of being centered:
[image]
Therefore, I tried using d-block and mx-auto to these buttons and they center correctly in responsive. However, then in large screens they separate:
[image]

Can mx-auto be only applied or disabled to a certain viewport?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the `d-flex` at all widths instead of `d-sm-flex`...

```
   <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
         <a class="btn botonhome mr-3 mb-3 " routerlink="/backoffice/job" routerlinkactive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
         <a class="btn botonhome mb-3 " routerlink="/backoffice/jobs" routerlinkactive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/sJTHRXBK4M

Answer (score 0):

to have your buttons stacked in small screens i placed the buttons in a row and then placed both buttons in seperate divs.

```
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
               <h1 class="textoprincipal text-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
             <a class="btn botonhome   mr-sm-3 mb-3 " routerLink="/backoffice/job" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
           </div>

             <div class="col-sm-6">
               <a class="btn  botonhome    mb-3 " routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
       <!--<div class="contain bg-danger">-->
       <!--<img class="gear contain" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Cog%2C_Web_Fundamentals.svg">-->

       <!--</div>-->
   </section>
```